# Combine 2 url filter in one cell google spreadsheet, "ga:pagePath==/url1,url2"

Tags: api, google-sheets, filter, google-analytics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNSFT.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNSFT.png)

I have a website with 5 pages on it. Every filter on google sheets using google analytics API is written like:

```
ga:pagePath==/home,ga:pagePath==/,ga:pagePath==/mapa,ga:pagePath==/producto,ga:pagePath==/horario,ga:pagePath==/pago.
```

I want to mix "/home" and "/", I think something like ga:pagePath==//|/home?
please help. there is a picture explaining I want to save both values in one cell.

It's like 780+525 in one cell

Thanks guys I'm new to the business

Answer (score 1):

You have to use tilde symbol for regex, like this:

```
ga:pagePath=~^/$|/home
```